# Maintaining sort order for larger list objects in python

Tags: python

I need to convert a list into dictionary with a sequential index whilst maintaining the order of `a` ESPECIALLY when `a` is fairly large > 10k

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a = [3, 3, 11, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 7, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
b = list(range(len(a)))
```

when I use the following code for when lengths  of (a) are small <0.1k

```
result = OrderedDict(zip(a, b))
print(result)
```

I get predictable expected results

However, when the list `a` is quite large the ordered dict fails to work and maintain original order?

`OrderedDict([(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)])` etc

and not:

`OrderedDict([(0,3), (1,3), (2,11)])` as I should wish.

any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: dict keys are unique, this might be what you overlooked?

Comment: Both your `OrderedDict` results have duplicate values. By construction, this isn't possible.

Comment: Can you post code that actually provides a large enough data set that the unexpected results are visible in testing?

Comment: @Chris_Rands, But `b = list(range(len(a)))`, so each value in `b` is unique, right? If you `zip(a, b)`, you can never have 2 values in `a` mapping to the same value in `b`.

Comment: Trivial example: `dict(zip((3, 3, 11), (0, 1, 2)))`. You won't find 2 keys mapped to the same value if the values are a range. OP has defined values as a range.

Comment: Did you mean `OrderedDict(zip(b, a))`?

Answer (score 0):

An `OrderedDict` (or a Python 3.7+ `dict`) remembers key-insertion order no matter the length of the
 (key, value)-pair list passed to the constructor.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> kvs = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 5)]
>>> OrderedDict(kvs)
OrderedDict([(1, 5), (3, 4)])
```

In the example above, the key `1` is duplicated. Since the `OrderedDict` remembers `1` as the first key, its value is updated to `5` when the tuple `(1, 5)` is encountered but the position for key `1` does not change.